# In a topological space, can the neighbourhood of a point be arbitrarily large?

Tags: general-topology

I am learning the basics of topology to eventually take a run at relativity, the "neighbourhood" of a point in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is any open set that includes the point p. But the word "neighbourhood", at least in the everyday context implies some closeness, but the definition given doesn't seem to imply any limit on size. My question is can the open set containing a point $p$ be arbitrarily large and still be its "neighbourhood"?

Comment: There is no notion of "large" in general and "neighborhood" of a point is indeed an open set containing the point. For example, if the topology has only the empty set and the whole space, there is only one neighborhood.

Comment: Oh does the open set we choose to define "neighbourhood" have to be an element of the topology? Also if we have the discrete topology (which to my understanding is all open sets in X) is every point in X in the neighbourhood of every other point in that case? And if the topology contains only the empty set and the whole space surely this is the same case, since the only set that can define the neighbourhood is therefore the full set itself?

Comment: (1) Yes, a "neighborhood" by definition is an open set, so it's an element of the topology. (2) Nitpick: the discrete topology is when you declare all subsets of $X$ to be open, since before placing a topology on a set you don't know what "open" means. But then yes, every point is in a neighborhood of any other point, since if you have two points $x$,$y$ then $\{x,y\}$ is an open set in the discrete topology. (3) If you have the trivial topology, yes--you're correct again. (All of this assuming your space has at least 2 points, though.)

Comment: Thank you for your help that's all clear now.

Comment: Sometimes the word "neighborhood" refers to any subset containing an open set which contains $p$. The open sets containing $p$ are then called "open neighborhoods". This terminology is particularly useful when talking about "compact neighborhoods".

Comment: Ah, true. Thanks for pointing that out. In the case that your definition is the one the OP is using, then the OP's comments are still correct regarding the trivial and discrete topologies; the only thing that wouldn't go through is my comment "(1)"--this is why it's important to check conventions :)

Answer (score 3):

In math words mean what the definitions say, not what it seems they should mean by analogy with common usage. If $X$ is a topological space and $x\in X$ then $X$ is a neighborhood of $x$, by definition.

Comment: This is to take the extreme case that the neighborhood can be the entire topological space.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question: yes.

However, we usually have in mind not just one neighborhood of a point, but a collection of many neighborhoods which zoom in arbitrarily close to the point. These are the interesting neighborhoods because they are a way of specifying “closeness” to the point.

For example, a function between two topological spaces enjoys the property of continuity at a particular domain point $x$ if points close to $x$ have images close to $f(x)$.  This means that for any given neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ (no matter how small it is), there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ (sufficiently small) such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.

And so on.